# Book: Crash landed Colony ship, when night falls something makes colonists feral

Tags: story-identification, space-colonization

I read part of this when I was 12 or 13ish about the 1997 time frame and it was not new. I'm pretty sure it was pollen that caused the feral behavior (behavior returned to normal afterwards). Orgies were involved. If i remember correctly hard cover had a lunar eclipse on it.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You may want to take the [tour], to understand how the site works. This is certainly a good start, but you may still want to check out the answers to [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/), see if any of the suggestions prompt additional memories, and edit them into your question. For instance, the feral behavior seems triggered by nightfall; does that mean everyone went back to normal once the sun rose again, or once triggered did it seem permanent?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the sparse details it sounds vaguely like [Darkover Landfall](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?5361) by Marion Zimmer Bradley.

A colony ship goes off course and crashes on an unknown planet. There is some sort of hallucinogenic pollen that cause the colonists to engage in totally uninhibited behavior, including murder and orgies.

Comment: I am fairly certain that you are correct. Thank you!